# How to uninstall apache from the command line on Mac?

Tags: apache, user-interface, command-line, terminal, xampp

I followed these directions to install apache for a class on the following link on the command line aka terminal:

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

but then my professor told me that we needed to install XAMPP 5.6.12 which will have packages including:

```
Apache 2.4.16
MySQL 5.6.26
PHP 5.6.12
phpMyAdmin 4.4.14
```

So now I want to uninstall the current apache(Apache/2.4.25) on my mac so that I can install XAMMP which will already have apache and the other packages that I need for my gui class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check the output of below command and whether the apache is running under _www user

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

Stop the built-in Apache server in Mac OS X is by using this command:

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
```

Enter administrator password.

Next run this launchctl unload command

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Check with the first command again whether the built-in apache server is completely gone
Stopped and disavowed

Comment: after I entered sudo apachectl -k stop command i get the following message:

AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for Hussains-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

What should I do from here

Comment: Check httpd.conf in folder /etc/apache2, or should have apache2.conf - simply add:  ServerName localhost

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: any editor would be okay to do vi httpd.conf or apache2.conf. Add the line-> ServerName localhost

Comment: So I did sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf then inputted my password and added the line ServerName localhost and saved it and then typed sudo apachectl -k stop(it didnt ask me for a password) then I did sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist and nothing happened so I ran the first command again sudo lsof -i:80 and nothing happened. Does this mean apache is gone from my mac and I can now install XAMMP without any worries?

Comment: If you don't get any details printed with the second time execution of sudo lsof -I:80 that means your apache is disabled completely

Answer (score 2):

Now with macOS [Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina), the following sequence to disable the Apache HTTPD daemon is:

```sh
$ sudo apachectl stop
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```

As to whether one should remove the /usr/sbin/http

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apachectl start` to make sure it is running

go to http://localhost:80 to ensure you see "It Works!" or something comes up to confirm it is running.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

`cat /private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.plist` should produce output similar to the following to show that httpd has been disabled from autostarting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.ftpd</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.mdmclient.daemon.runatboot</key>
    <true/>
    <key>org.apache.httpd</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands, works for me on MacOS Ventura M2

```
sudo apachectl stop 
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```